# How do I add my custom classes to a AWS Lambda Layer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to figure out how to add my classes to an AWS Lambda layer. I have already added a custom library and gotten that to work, but following the same process seems to not work. I have tried zipping the classes up in a nodejs folder, and also have tried with the classes being within a node_modules folder within the nodejs folder.

Lastly, assuming they can be added, how do I import them into my lambda function to use?

```
const uuid = require("uuidv4").default;

module.exports = class Order {
    constructor
    (userId, exchange, market, trades, status, closed) 
    {
        this.orderId = uuid();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.items = items;
        this.status = status;
        this.closed = closed;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the files (with your classes) to the nodejs directory, zip it and upload it into a Lambda layer.

Layers are extracted to the /opt directory in the function execution environment. Each runtime looks for libraries in a different location under /opt, depending on the language. For Node, you would require your classes as follows:

```
const myclass = require('/opt/nodejs/myclass');
```

Comment: for uuid I just have to do require('uuidv4") just FYI. It works already in other lambda services... Will try to require the 2 classes I am trying to add to the layer and then ill report back here! Ty

Comment: that seems to of worked ty! I didnt see the /opt location mentioned anywhere online!!